# Finder keeps crashing even in Yosemite 10.10.3

Tags: finder, time-machine, crash

I have had a lot of crashes by Finder especially when trying to delete a file. At first I thought it may be because of "Quicklook extensions" I installed e.g. to quickly look at markdown file and removed all of them but it didn't help. My second guess was a bug in XtraFinder so uninstalled it also and again it didn't change anything. Looking at Console I see this error everytime Finder crashes:

> 10/04/2015 16:17:49.492 Finder[24563]: Attempt to use XPC with a
>   MachService that has HideUntilCheckIn set. This will result in
>   unpredictable behavior: com.apple.backupd.status.xpc

Anybody had this before and solved it? Please let me know how.

PS: Despite what you may think I even didn't set TimeMachine backups so there is no backup operation on this mac!

Comment: Could you edit this to not ask "has anyone seen this" - since that leads to answers like "yes" and "no" and discussion. My guess is you want to know how to troubleshoot this or if that specific message is logged when people don't have Finder crashing. Try to be specific about what you want so that we can answer the problem rather than guess what you want. My guess is that message is unrelated. I have 844 events logged from (3/11/15 12:00:00.000 AM to 4/10/15 11:21:10.000 AM) with that backup status xpc message and zero finder crashes.

Answer (score -1):

I have read that trashing the finder plist fixes the crashing. You'll find directions about how to do this in a Google search

Comment: Could you include instructions on how to do this within your answer?